# Libgdx Android game Crash after short time

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, box2d

first of all, i am from germany and still in school so sorry for my poor english. 
I am trying to make a 2D Plattformer for Android, using Libgdx, Box2d and Tiled,  and everything worked fine till began to work on stuff that the player could collect(coins and hearts). I placed circle objects in tiled  and made the bodies and fixtures in eclipse. At contact i add the particular body to an array and after a worldstep i check the array, if it contains a body it will be destroyed and the array cleared. My problem now is that after a really short amount of time where the runs as it is supposed to, it will just freeze. But if i run the desktopversion it doesn't freeze(testet it for a while). I searched on the internet for similar problems but solutions to them didn't help me, so i decided to register myself on this site where i am normally finding my answers.
I added all code that i think could have something to do with this and also all of my error messages.

### My play screen

```
public Test(MyGame game,int state ,Content content) {
    super(game,state);
    this.content = content;
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor());
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -5.81f), true);
    cl = new MyContactListener(this);
    world.setContactListener(cl);

    b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    b2dCam = new OrthographicCamera();
    b2dCam.setToOrtho(false, MyGame.WIDTH / PPM, MyGame.HEIGHT / PPM);

    jumpButton= new Rectangle(hudCam.viewportWidth/8*3 ,-hudCam.viewportHeight/2,hudCam.viewportWidth/8,hudCam.viewportWidth/8);
    leftButton= new Rectangle(-hudCam.viewportWidth/2,-hudCam.viewportHeight/2,hudCam.viewportWidth/8,hudCam.viewportWidth/8);
    rightButton= new Rectangle(-hudCam.viewportWidth/8*3,-hudCam.viewportHeight/2,hudCam.viewportWidth/8,hudCam.viewportWidth/8);
    pauseButton= new Rectangle(hudCam.viewportWidth/8*3 ,hudCam.viewportHeight/2-hudCam.viewportWidth/8,hudCam.viewportWidth/8,hudCam.viewportWidth/8);
    menuButton = new Rectangle(hudCam.viewportWidth/12,-hudCam.viewportHeight/16*3,hudCam.viewportWidth/12*3,hudCam.viewportWidth/8);
    againButton = new Rectangle(-hudCam.viewportWidth/6*2,-hudCam.viewportHeight/16*3,hudCam.viewportWidth/12*3,hudCam.viewportWidth/8);
    createMap();
    createWorldBoxes();
    createPlayer();
    createCollectible();



public void update(float delta) {
    xsp=player.getBody().getLinearVelocity().x;
    handleInput();
    world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1, 1);

    //remove coinBodies
    Array<Body> bodies = cl.getCoinBodies();
    for(int i = 0; i < bodies.size; i++) {
        if(bodies.get(i) != null){
        Body b = bodies.get(i);
        coins.removeValue((Coin)b.getUserData(), true);
        world.destroyBody(bodies.get(i));
    //   add coin value
        //play sound
        }
    }
    bodies.clear();

    //remove heartBodies
    bodies = cl.getHeartBodies();
    for(int i = 0; i < bodies.size; i++) {
        if(bodies.get(i) != null){
            Body b = bodies.get(i);
            hearts.removeValue((Heart)b.getUserData(), true);
            world.destroyBody(bodies.get(i));
            player.increaseLife(1);
        //  player.collectCrystal(); add coin value
        //play sound
    }
    }
    bodies.clear(); 


    //delete collected things, increase live(decrease life)

    player.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());




    for(int i = 0; i < coins.size; i++) {
        coins.get(i).update(delta);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < hearts.size; i++) {
        hearts.get(i).update(delta);
    }

}
```

I skipped some things the render method for example.

### My contactlistener

```
public class BBContactListener implements ContactListener {

private int numFootContacts;
private Array<Body> bodiesToRemove;
private boolean playerDead;

public BBContactListener() {
    super();
    bodiesToRemove = new Array<Body>();
}

public void beginContact(Contact contact) {

    Fixture fa = contact.getFixtureA();
    Fixture fb = contact.getFixtureB();

    if(fa == null || fb == null) return;

    if(fa.getUserData() != null && fa.getUserData().equals("foot")) {
        numFootContacts++;
    }
    if(fb.getUserData() != null && fb.getUserData().equals("foot")) {
        numFootContacts++;
    }

    if(fa.getUserData() != null && fa.getUserData().equals("crystal")) {
        bodiesToRemove.add(fa.getBody());
    }
    if(fb.getUserData() != null && fb.getUserData().equals("crystal")) {
    bodiesToRemove.add(fb.getBody());
    }

    if(fa.getUserData() != null && fa.getUserData().equals("spike")) {
        playerDead = true;
    }
    if(fb.getUserData() != null && fb.getUserData().equals("spike")) {
        playerDead = true;
    }

}

public void endContact(Contact contact) {

    Fixture fa = contact.getFixtureA();
    Fixture fb = contact.getFixtureB();

    if(fa == null || fb == null) return;

    if(fa.getUserData() != null && fa.getUserData().equals("foot")) {
        numFootContacts--;
    }
    if(fb.getUserData() != null && fb.getUserData().equals("foot")) {
        numFootContacts--;
    }

}

public boolean playerCanJump() { return numFootContacts > 0; }
public Array<Body> getBodies() { return bodiesToRemove; }
public boolean isPlayerDead() { return playerDead; }

public void preSolve(Contact c, Manifold m) {}
public void postSolve(Contact c, ContactImpulse ci) {}
```

}

I get lots of these  errors.

> 06-09 03:24:05.268: E/Trace(19264): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Of these too.

> 06-09 03:23:26.126: E/Crashlytics(19117): Crashlytics must be initialized by calling Crashlytics.start(Context) prior to logging messages.

also different ones of these "could not find class" errors.

> 06-09 03:22:04.549: E/dalvikvm(19002): Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Action$Builder', referenced from method b.a

Some sensor errors

> 06-09 03:16:49.172: E/Sensors(617): Error while trying to enable 9 axis sensor fusion : 22

I get these even if the game freezes

> 06-09 03:29:21.615: E/overlay(263): [HWC] handleEvent: state changed OV_BYPASS_3_LAYER-->OV_CLOSED
>   06-09 03:30:27.516: E/overlay(263): [HWC] handleEvent: state changed OV_CLOSED-->OV_BYPASS_3_LAYER

i just remembered that i changed the project compliance and jre to 1.7 so i could use the switch statement with strings.

i hope this is enough information but in case you need could need more let just let me know.

thank you for reading and hopefully answering too.

Comment: Sorry i used the wrong filter in logcat, the only error i get know is the trace error 
06-09 03:37:39.707: E/Trace(20479): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: Why do you clear arraylist just make local array list since you getCoins array From an other class. Maybe arraylist index mess up in loops going outofbound. You don't need physics for platform tho. You can just do without and you do not need arraylist for physics since you knOw what objects colide

Comment: You're probably mutating a list that is in use somehow (bodies.get(i) is wrong at the end of the loop).  Try commenting out the `removeValue`/`destroyBody` calls and see if the problem goes away (or change to a mode where you set a flag "invisible" on the "destroyed" objects, so they stay in the array, etc.)

Comment: thank you for replying,
i tried that and it seems to keep the game from crashing. But how should i remove the animation and the body ?